# JPA - "no Metadata found for type" exception

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, persistence

The JPA implementation used in my application is Kodo.
When attempting to query the DB for an entity, I get this very weird exception:

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: No metadata was found for type "class **com.verid.ims.model.AddressUS**". The class does not appear in the list of persistent types: [com.verid.ims.model.Birthdate, com.verid.ims.model.PersonName, **com.verid.ims.model.AddressUS**, com.rsa.idv.ims.feedback.IMSFeedback, com.rsa.idv.ims.notification.IMSNotification, com.rsa.idv.ims.provider.IMSProvider, com.rsa.idv.ims.notification.NotificationEntry, com.rsa.idv.ims.enroll.SecretUserQuestion, com.rsa.idv.ims.enroll.Enrollment].

Please take into account that the AddressUS class, which according to the exception does not appear in the list of persistent types, is actually in the list! (Bold)

The AddressUS class is mapped in my orm.xml file (it's not in the persistence.xml descriptor since it's not an entity, only an embeddable). Here is the mapping:

```
<embeddable class="com.verid.ims.model.AddressUS">
  <attributes>
    <basic name="city" />
    <basic name="state">
      <enumerated>STRING</enumerated>
    </basic>
   <basic name="street1" />
   <basic name="street2" />
   <basic name="zipcode" />
   <basic name="suite" />
  </attributes>
</embeddable>
```

Needless to say, the persistence.xml descriptor refers to the orm.xml file.

The exception only happens on some environments (not all of them), which basically means that it's an environmental problem. What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that have same problem. But it is incosistent behaviour. Application works fine some time (few days) and then suddenly this problem appears. We have cluster and that problem occures on only one server in cluster.

After restart of application, OpenJPA again works fine.

We also have problem where OpenJPA works fine till some moment and then start to generate invalid query for some table. It seems like class or database metadata have corrupted in some moment. After problem occures, invalid query is generated.

Do you have some new information about this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no information that can help. I tried to use the PCEnhancer that ships with WebLogic in order to enhance the persisted classes (a practice I've seen done in other parts of the application), which didn't help.
The problem only happens on clustered environments, but unlike your case, it always fails, and restart doesn't help.